# CarrierWave keeping the filename constant for thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to rename the files uploaded via `CarrierWave` and also creating multiple versions of it.

**Uploader**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class DisplayPhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::ImageOptimizer

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted: #{model.name.to_s.underscore}
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.pluralize.parameterize}/"
  end

  process :optimize => [{ quality: 90 }]

  #process :blur => [0, 8]

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end
  version :medium do
    process :resize_to_fill => [128, 128]
  end
  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
  end
  version :tiny do
    process :resize_to_fill => [32, 32]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

  def filename
    if original_filename
      "#{model.name.parameterize}-#{SecureRandom.hex(4)}.#{file.extension}"
    end
  end


end
```

When i upload the file - it generated the images and thumbnails peacefully. 
But the file-name is getting randomized for every thumbnail created. How can i keep the file name constant after its generated first time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to generate **one** random key, store it in the model and use it every time a filename is generated.

So first you have to extend the model, that mounts the uploader and give it a `secure_token` (type: string).

then in your uploader add:

```
  def filename
    if original_filename.present?
      # add or replace secure token
      original_filename.sub! /_^[0-9a-f]{16}._/,'.'
      "#{secure_token}_#{original_filename}"
    end
  end

  protected

  # use ONE secure token per instance
  def secure_token
    if model.respond_to? :secure_token
      model.secure_token ||= SecureRandom.hex(8)
    else  # use some fix insecure token
      '09ca7dcb65fcafea'
    end
  end
```